Hosting client react app with npm start equivalent to server side rendering?
I'm figuring out how to host a React, Node and Express app. If I take the react client that I've got and run npm start on AWS Lightsail, is that considered server side rendering, and would it be a valid solution?

No, it's not server side rendering. It's local vs remote hosting. If you see that a server serves HTML layout you'd expect from the app in page source (Ctrl+U), that's SSR. It's unknown what's your app and what goals SSR is supposed to serve in your case. Switch to SSR framework like Next or Remix or use a prerender service to avoid rewrites
